Curve starting at vertex of a cone with a given tangent direction stays inside the cone for a short period of time?
While working on some algebraic stuff, I was led to the following situtation:
Assume we have two points $x_0\neq y_0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The vector starting at $x_0$ and ending in $y_0$ is denoted by $\vec{v}$.
Denote by $B$ the open ball around $y_0$ with some radius $r>0$ and by $C$ the cone over $B$ with vertex in $x_0$ (i.e. $C$ is the convex hull of $\{x_0\}$ and $B$).
Now we also have a $C^1$-curve $\gamma: (-a,a) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ (for some $a>0$) such that: $\gamma(0)=x_0$ and $\gamma'(0)=\lambda\vec{v}$ for some $\lambda >0$.
Can I find some $a'>0$ with $0<a'\leqslant a$ such that $\gamma((0,a'))\subset C\setminus\{x_0\}$?
In some ways this looks like the "Curve Selection Lemma" except that I already have a curve $\gamma$ going through a fixed point $x_0$ and with a fixed tangent vector $\vec{w}=\lambda\vec{v}$ pointing to the center of base of the cone $C$.
Drawing a picture for $n=2$, the existence of $a'$ seems likely to be true since $\gamma$ goes through $x_0$ in the direction of $y_0$ at $t=0$. But I cannot come up with a rigorous argument. Any hints / help is appreciated.

tl; dr: Yes, such an $a'$ exists.
Use the fact $\gamma$ is $C^{1}$ (in fact, differentiable is enough) to write $\gamma(t) = x_{0} + tv + E(t)$ with $|E(t)|/t \to 0$ as $|t| \to 0$.
Now decompose the error $E(t)$ into components $T(t)$ along the axis of $C$ and $P(t)$ perpendicular to the axis. (Explicitly, if $e = v/|v|$ is the unit vector positively parallel to $v$, then $T(t) = E(t) \cdot e$ and $P(t) = E(t) - T(t)$.) Particularly:

$\gamma(t) = x_{0} + \bigl(tv + T(t)\bigr) + P(t)$,
$P(t)$ is the (perpendicular Euclidean) distance from $\gamma(t)$ to the cone axis, and
In Landau notation, $T(t)$ and $P(t)$  are both $o(t)$.

The "absolute slope" of $\gamma(t)$ relative to the axis of the cone is therefore
$$
\frac{\text{distance to axis}}{\text{distance from $x_{0}$ along axis}}
  = \frac{|P(t)|}{|tv + T(t)|}
  = \frac{|P(t)|}{t\bigl(|v| + o(1)\bigr)}
  = \frac{o(1)}{|v| + o(1)}
  = o(1).
$$
Since the cone $C$ has a fixed positive slope $m_{0}$, there is an interval about $0$ where the absolute slope of $\gamma(t)$ is smaller than $m_{0}$, i.e., $\gamma(t)$ lies inside $C$.

Thanks a lot! This looks good.
